# Metasploit Log or Additional Information Re: Exploit completed, but no session was created

Tags: exploit, metasploit

Almost all of my personal lab work with Metasploit has been unsuccessful. Most commonly I get the message "Exploit completed, but no session was created." I don't know what to do after this happens. Is there any way to read a log or discover more information about why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Its Metasploit way telling you the exploit failed , because the system is patched and not vulnerable to this exploit, Or  possibly  that you have configured your payload handler wrong and so the payload code can't connect back.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please explain what you mean about configuring the payload handler wrong? Could the problem be that the port is blocked or not open?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I used "handler" then it worked and the session was opened.

Try this:

```
handler -H LHOST/RHOST -P LPORT/RPORT -p payload
```